# Can i run my raspberry pi 24x7 with the solar power bank?

Tags: power-supply

I wanted to run the pi with a pi cam and internet module for 24x7 for lifelong, can i do that if i am using a 10000mah solar power bank
https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07DB5FT9H/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_y01fFbCBZ5Q7S
I have posted the link, can anyone please tell me if this will work??

Answer (score 2):

If you can add & subtract, you can work this out for yourself:

- [Output voltage: 5.1V/2.1A](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07DB5FT9H/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_y01fFbCBZ5Q7S)
- [Raspberry Pi Power Consumption](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md)

Comment: Could get tricky at night, unless you get a lunar power bank as well.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: It could indeed :)